# In pickleball, why is the doubles game more highly regarded than the singles game?

Tags: pickleball

An [article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/sports/2022/09/20/pickleball-growth-tennis/) about pickleball says the following:

> Among pros and amateurs alike, the doubles game is more popular and highly regarded than singles.

I guess if an amateur is just playing casually as a social activity, then that might explain why they would prefer to play doubles over singles.

But why would pro pickleball players prefer doubles over singles? In all other sports I can think of where there are singles and doubles matches (e.g. tennis, table tennis, badminton), most players would probably prefer to win a singles championship over a doubles championship, because winning the singles title would mean they are the best player, whereas winning the doubles title would not necessarily mean they are the best player.